# Ocultar extensão de pdf na URL

Tags: url, pdf

Necessito esconder a extensão do arquivo pdf que é aberto no meu sistema web. Fiz algumas pesquisa e vi que da para fazer pelo htacces, mas não obtive sucesso. Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Veja http://forum.imasters.com.br/topic/504037-ocultar-a-extensao-php-da-urlhtaccess/. acho que pode te ajudar

Comment: Obrigado pela dica

Comment: Que bom que te ajudou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode fazer isso usando seu arquivo `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.pdf -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.pdf
```

Comment: Fiz o teste e não deu certo... Eu acho eu eu tenho que passar o caminho todo da URL e no final colocar a extensão. A minha URL é esta aqui: /gedphp/upload/id_do_registro/arquivo.pdf.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda novamente.

Answer (score 4):

Consegui fazer o que eu queria.
A minha URL era a seguinte: /gedphp/upload/id_do_registro/arquivo.pdf. Portanto utilizei as seguintes configurações:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.pdf -f
RewriteRule ^upload/([0-9]+)/(.+)$ upload/$1/$2.pdf
```